# How to force Federated signout redirect to login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, federated-identity

I'm using WSFederationAuthentication module for authentication. I want this: after user press logout button, he signs out (delete all cookies) and redirect to login page. 
I have this code for logout button:

```
var ls = new LoginStatus();
ls.LogoutAction = LogoutAction.Redirect;
ls.LogoutPageUrl = {some URL, where I have sign out code}
```

Signout part:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
String signoutURL = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(
authModule.Issuer,
{login Url},
null);

WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(
new Uri(signoutURL),
new Uri(authModule.Realm));
```

This code really do signout and delete cookies, but does not redirect to login page. Still, url, that users sees contains this part:
    &wreply={loginUrl}

As I understand wreply parameter does not always is used.

Instead of using FederatedSignOut() method I tried this one:

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(signoutURL);
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Redirect(LoginUrl);
```

But, this doesn't really do sign out. When user tries to log in next time, he doesn't need to enter any credentials and is signed in automatically. My guess, not all cookies are deleted.

So, there is my question, how can I do sign out and force redirect to login page?

P.S. I also delete FedAuth cookies by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be, that redirect Url can be **only** Url, that is written in Idp config:

```
<passiveEndpoints>
<endpoint endpointType="WsFed" location="{this url}" binding="Post" />
</passiveEndpoints>
```

If `wreply` parameter value is any other url, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood how federated sign on and sign out work (I say this as you have neglected to mention what I would consider is the most important thing.)

When you attempt to login to an application that uses WS-Federation you are actually redirected to an identity provider (Idp) and you login to this Idp. Once logged into the Idp you will be redirected back to your site with a security token and you will then be logged in to your site also.

At this stage you are logged in to two applications in effect:

1. The Idp
2. Your web site

What are you trying to achieve?

1. Logging out of your site only
2. Federated Sign out (i.e. Signing out
   of the Idp and your site and any other relying partys)

If we are in case 1 then that is simple. Delete your cookies and you will be fine however you will still be logged into the Idp and so when a user navigates back to your site and gets redirected to the Idp they will likely be redirected back to your site with a security token without being prompted for credentials and will then be logged into your site again, which seems a bit pointless.

Given this, I think you are after scenario 2. Well in that case, the functionality you want actually depends on what software you are using for your Idp, something you have neglected to mention in the question.

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a generic way to do what you want with all Idp's and even more some Idp's won't directly support it.

I think it may be best raising a question about how your Idp works and how to get this to work. Also some very good things to include in the question would possibly be the URL's of your site and Idp (not for the purposes of "checking them out" but because other indirect solutions may be possible if they come under the same domain name). Also anything about your infrastructure of your Idp and site would also be helpful as again specific setups could give indirect solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> "If a wreply parameter was specified in the ACSSignOut cookie, the
>   JavaScript redirect to the address indicated by the wreply value to
>   complete the sign-out. Otherwise, the JavaScript redirects to the
>   Return URL of the relying party, as specified in the ACS Management
>   Portal."

**[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223670.aspx)**

Comment: Strangely, I don't have that cookie. Could it be called ABCSTSSignOut? Also, do you know format for that cookie?